# speedtest module in python

Tags: python, speed-test

i'm trying to use the speedtest module in python, i run "pip install speedtest-cli" as admin from command prompt, it works in the command prompt and gives me the results when running "speedtest-cli"
But in PyCharm it wont work, this is what I have

```
import speedtest

st = speedtest.Speedtest()
st.get_best_server()

ping = st.results.ping
download = st.download()
upload = st.upload()
```

and in console I get this:

```
File "C:/Users/utente/PycharmProjects/try/sptest.py", line 3, in <module>
    st = speedtest.Speedtest()
AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'
```

how can i solve this??

Comment: Are there any file named `speedtest.py` in your folder?

Comment: @OlvinRoght no, no other file named like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the `speedtest` package is empty. You need to install `speedtest-cli` instead. So,

`pip install speedtest-cli`

From you there you can do:

```
import speedtest
s = speedtest.Speedtest()

...
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First, uninstall `speedtest` module using `pip3 uninstall speedtest`
2. Finally, install `speedtest-cli` module using `pip3 install speedtest-cli`

Answer (score -2):

Use -

```
import speedtest as speedtest
```

Then Your Code Should Work.

Other Solution-(not recommended)
Except using

```
speedtest.Speedtest()
```

use only

```
Speedtest()
```

Comment: I tried both ways and it wont work! Are there other modules i could try to get ping, upload and download speed?

Comment: The error is attribute error so the module is completely imported. So check out the function names are they correct

Comment: Solved!! for some reason speedtest.py was empty

Comment: So this answer helped you so please mark it as excepted.